# Exportar datos de Excel a Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

Acabo de descargarme Matlab y necesitaría poder exportar todos los datos de cada hoja del fichero excel (.xlsx) a un archivo .MAT de Matlab de manera automática. 
Es un fichero de 1275 hojas y en cada hoja como 3100x10 datos.

Qué librerías y/o funciones necesitaría y cómo tengo que usarlos para poder automatizar este proceso de extracción de datos entre programas?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de como quieras guardar los datos.

Si tienes títulos en las tablas, los puedes guardar en la variable `texto`. Le tienes que pasar a la función el número de página que quieres guardar.

Aquí se están guardando como matrices, una hoja por capa, en `sheet`.

```
for i = 1:numero_de_hojas
    [sheet(:,:,1), texto(i,:)] = xlsread('prueba.xlsx',i);
end

save('guardado.mat','sheet','texto');
```